# Best preprocessing method for my regression task

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, data-preprocessing

I have a dataset:

```
X          Y
123        321
42         24
10         01
```

As you can see, Y is just the reverse of the input number, nothing special. The issue is I want a model which automatically determines that Y is the reverse of X. I did try linear regression and I split the input data into individual digits. That got me very close to the solution.

```
X1  X2  X3   Y
1   2   3    321
2   5   6    652
0   1   2    210
```

As you can see above, the last tuple is giving me the wrong answer. This is because it's taking the 0 in the X1 into account. How can I make a model which'll give me correct answer irrespective of the no. of digits in X?

Comment: Linear regression will not be able to address this issue. Your apparent partial success might just represent fortuitous results from your limited cases. This seems more like a text-processing problem rather than a statistical analysis problem.

Comment: Not really, I can think of a mathematical function to represent this problem. If it can be represented by a mathematical function, then linear regression can do it. X1*1+X2*10+X3*100. That's the mathematical function.
Plus it worked with 100% accuracy for inputs with same number of digits. Not a fluke.

Comment: Could you please explain what `X1`, `X2`, `X3` mean?  I cannot find any problem with the relationship exhibited in your second example: `Y` indeed is the sequence `X3`, `X2`, `X1`, *exactly as you have specified,* without error.

Comment: I broke down X into individual digits to create X1,X2 and X3. The issue is, if there is a 2 digit number involved, then I've to put 0 at the X1 position and during reverse, it includes that 0 too so 023 becomes 320. But I want 32. You get the issue I hope?

Comment: It would help (a great deal) to edit your post to show both what your procedure has produced *and what you intend it to produce.*  What I still don't understand is why you don't represent a value like $23$ by the vector $(2,3,0)$ instead of $(0,2,3)$ if your intention is that its reversal will be the number $32.$

Comment: I can and I should that perfectly solves the problem. Thank you :)